# Ruby: in `<top (required)>' from -e:1:in `load' from -e:1:in `<main>'

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir-webdriver

Here's my ruby script: To run this script I am using "JetBrains Ruby Mine"

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'cucumber'

Given(/^a user goes to website$/) do
  driver = Watir::Browser.new :ff
  driver.goto 'http://www.website.com'

end

When(/^user searches for "([^"]*)"$/) do |arg|
  driver.text_field(:id => 'searchtextbox').set "#{arg}"
  driver.send_keys :return
end

Then(/^website should return results for "([^"]*)"$/) do |arg|
  #pending
end
```

Here's `.feature` file for above script:

```
Feature: Website search functionality

  Scenario: Users can search for an specific item on website
    Given a user goes to website
    When user searches for "pens"
    Then website should return results for "pens"
```

On executing above script I am getting:

```
from C:/Users/Admin/RubymineProjects/my_project/features/step_definitions/website_search.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

To fix this I installed above gems in root directory of project, but still same error.

IRB output of lines script are here:

```
Switch to inspect mode.
>> >> require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'watir-webdriver'
=> true


?> ?> require 'cucumber'
require 'cucumber'
=> true

#opens browser window**
?> ?> driver = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
driver = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
?> driver.goto 'http://www.website.com'
=> #<Watir::Browser:0x30d36020 url="about:blank" title=""> 



driver.goto 'http://www.website.com'
=> "http://www.website.com/"

#Types pens in search box
?> ?> driver.text_field(:id => 'twotabsearchtextbox').set "#{"pens"}"
driver.text_field(:id => 'twotabsearchtextbox').set "#{"pens"}"
=> "" 

#Press enter/return
?> ?> driver.send_keys :return
driver.send_keys :return
=> ""
```

Comment: Can you do this in irb? So open the irb console in that directory and do: require 'watir-webdriver'

Comment: Ok now do the same again and then type: driver = Watir::Browser.new :ff

Comment: browser window opned...

Comment: Can you execute the script verbosly and show me the output?

Comment: Can you also add the cucumber profile line + the command line you use to launche your tests ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing the results above, everything seems fine to me. It's just that you need to run `.feature` file and not the `.rb` script file.
OR

If you want to run via terminal/command line simply use:

`cucumber feature_file_name`